# How we can use unique value in arraylist hash map?

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

I have a problem with an arraylist hashmap. I want to add counter values in an arraylist hashmap. I have lot of counter values on different buttons. So I want to add these counter values. But it adds double and duplicates value in arraylist hash map.

My sample code is:

```
HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
String c = textcounter.getText().toString();
String d = txtdesc.getText().toString();            
st1=String.valueOf(button.getNextFocusForwardId());
st2=String.valueOf(button.getId());
System.out.println("----st1 value "+st1);
System.out.println("---st2--value "+st2);

String pval=String.valueOf(p);


map1.put("PID", pval);
map1.put("DESP", d);
map1.put("PRICE", prc);             
map1.put("COUNTER_VAL", c);

if(!myorder.contains(map1)) {
    myorder.add(map1);
}
if(myorder.contains(map1))
{

    for(HashMap<String, String> hm : myorder)
    {
        hm.put("COUNTER_VAL", c);
    }
}

System.out.println("Final value of My order"+ myorder);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already added `COUNTER_VAL` to `map1`. Then you loop through all maps in your order and add the same `COUNTER_VAL` to all of them. Is that what you want to be doing? It seems like you don't need to do that at all.

Comment: Actually I have to perform add to cart function on masonry list. On masonry one web service call to get data field product_id,pro_desc,price, and user can select multiple items from masonry list and counter will rotate and each product has its on counter and user will counter simultaneously and value will add list will generate but I don't want duplicate value add to list and counter will also move.

Comment: So you have separate counters for each item instead of a 'global' counter?

Answer (score 0):

Could be because you say:

```
if(!myorder.contains(map1))                 
    myorder.add(map1);
}
if(myorder.contains(map1)) // this is always true cos you just inserted it above...
```

Comment: Good catch: missed that one. In that case I'm very confused what the OP is up to ;-)

Comment: Anybody help me about my problem

Answer (score 0):

How to add masonary layout in android with paging OR loadmore option

sample code is

public void oncreateProduct_List(int countm) {

```
    String testurl = URL1 + "prod/"+countm;

//  String testurl = URL1 + "sandy_scandy/"+counter;        
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000);       
    JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
    JSONObject json1 = jParser.getJSONfromUrl(testurl);
    try {
        JSONArray prod = json1.getJSONArray("prod");

        for ( i = 0; i < prod.length(); i++) {                  
            JSONObject prd = prod.getJSONObject(i);
            p_id = prd.getString("p_id");
            cat_id = prd.getString("cat_id");
            barcode = prd.getString("barcode");
            p_name = prd.getString("p_name");
            price = prd.getString("price");
            desp = prd.getString("desp");
            image = prd.getString("image");
            status = prd.getString("status");
            timestamp = prd.getString("timestamp");
            cat_name = prd.getString("cat_name");

            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(image).getContent());

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }               

            HashMap<String, String>map1= new HashMap<String, String>();
            map1.put("IMAGE", image);

            pro_id = p_id;              
            create_layout(pro_id,bitmap);

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("error", e.toString());
    }

    //countm++; 


}
private class LoadViewTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    // Before running code in the separate thread
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyShopping_List.this);



        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);





        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {



        try {

            synchronized (this) {

                int counter = 0;

                while (counter <= 10) {

                    this.wait(300);

                    counter++;



                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

        progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {         

            oncreateProduct_List(countm);   

            /*Scroll_main.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {


                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {                         

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
                         Thread.yield(); 


                          try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }   
                          new LoadViewTask().execute();
                             oncreateProduct_List(countm);                  
                             countm++;
                        } 


                    return false;
                }
    });         */



        progressDialog.dismiss();

    }

}
```

and call touch listener

Scroll_main.setOnTouchListener(new  View.OnTouchListener() {

```
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        float yValue=event.getY();
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();           
            int height = display.getHeight();  
            int scrollheight =Scroll_main.getHeight();
            System.out.println("Screen Height>"+height);
        System.out.println("value of scroll main  ="+scrollheight);
        //int ss=height-181;
        //height=(height*90)/100;
        if((yValue)<scrollheight){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Heloo"+height, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } /*elseif((Scroll_main.getHeight()-yValue)>=height){


                new LoadViewTask().execute();
                oncreateProduct_List(countm);

                countm = countm--;

                height=height--;
        }   */
        else{
            new LoadViewTask().execute();
            countm = countm ++;
            oncreateProduct_List(countm);               
            scrollheight=scrollheight++;

        }



        return false;
    }

});
```